# Matching results to the very next sequence in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a Job #, a Job Suffix, and a Job Sequence. I am trying to match a table to itself and pull in the very next sequence so if it is job 00001, suffix 001, and sequence 100, I want to join those results to the next sequence which for this example could be 200, but is not always, and display the results as 00001, 001, 100, 200. I have gotten the matches to find all higher sequences, but cannot narrow it down to just select the lowest of the matches

```
select a.job, a.sfx, a.seq, b.seq, from a 
left join b 
on a.job=b.job and a.sfx=b.sfx 
where a.seq<b.seq
```

Example of table:

```
|  Job  | Sfx | Seq |
| 00001 | 001 | 100 | 
| 00001 | 001 | 200 | 
| 00001 | 001 | 300 |
```

Results of current query:

```
|  Job  | Sfx | Seq  | b.seq |
| 00001 | 001 |  100 |   200 | 
| 00001 | 001 |  100 |   300 |
```

It is okay for the results to repeat for each subsequent sequence, e.x. seq 200 has a row matched to 300, and 300 is left unmatched to any row, but for sequences with more than 1 match I only want to see the min sequence it matches to, please let me know if that is unclear.

Thank you

Comment: it would help when you provide a [mre] see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: nbk, I have tried following the steps in the FAQ provided. Let me know if this is satisfactory, I will work on creating a link that will allow for actual querying to test on.

Comment: If it's just the one column you need then `lead(Seq) over (partition by Job, Sfx order by Seq)` is probably all you need. The join becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Unfortunately Lead and Partition are not recognized in my PSQL database

Comment: You must have a really old version. Try using a scalar subquery `(select min(b.seq) from b where b.Job = a.Job and b.Sfx = a.Sfx)` Or take what you've got and use `group by a.Job, a.Sfx, a.seq`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use the `LEAD` function, you may try the following:

```
SELECT A.Job, A.Sfx, A.Seq, MIN(B.Seq) B_seq 
FROM table_name A LEFT JOIN table_name B
ON A.Job = B.Job
AND A.Seq < B.Seq
GROUP BY A.Job, A.Sfx, A.Seq
ORDER BY A.Job, A.Sfx, A.Seq
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/36lWlbXl).

Comment: This is beautifully simple, cannot believe I did not think to select from a subquery. This works exactly as required, and I am very grateful.

Comment: Wrapping the inner query doesn't accomplish anything other than changing the names of the columns and removing the ones in common to the two tables.

Comment: @shawnt00, thank you for your feedback, I was preparing a query using row_number, I forgot to remove the outer query.

Comment: I understand how that goes.